# Downcasting NSObject in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I am learning Swift and am trying to understand something regarding downcasting. NSDictionary is represented in Swift as [NSObject:AnyObject]. From what I can tell, this can be downcasted to more specific types (e.g. [Int: String]). I get that NSObject is the base class when we're talking about Objective-C, but how is it that in Swift it can be downcasted to, say, a String or Integer? It was my understanding that Swift native types aren't subclasses from NSObject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question! What's actually happening is some magic in the interaction between Objective-C and Swift to make your life easier: you can downcast to, for example, `[String: Int]` if your original `NSDictionary` contains `NSString`s and `NSNumber`s. While `NSString` and `NSNumber` are indeed different types than `String` and `Int`, there is such an obvious correlation that Apple decided to do the conversion for you. In other words, it works for the same reason that this works:

```
let object = NSNumber(value: 4)
let swiftVersion = object as Int
```